# Can connect to SQL Server remotely by port number but not by instance name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Datacenter running on Windows Server 2008.

I am unable to connect to a named instance \SQL2008R2 using its instace name over the internet from my development machine (e.g. mydbserver.com\SQL2008R2 from SSMS).

The instance is configured to listen on port 49180.  If I try to connect using the specific port number everything works okay (e.g. mydbserver.com,49180 from SSMS).

The SQL Server Browser service is running, and I have opened UDP port 1434 on the server firewall (inbound and outbound).

I have no problems connecting a range of SQL Server instances from my machine. I have also tried connecting from a couple of other machines with no luck.

It seems to me that SQL Server Browser might not not be serving up the port number to my machine - is there any way to confirm/fix this?  Or could it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is wrong with the browser. Try restarting the SQL Browser service.

Comment: Have done lots of times to no avail. I'm now convinced that it can only work using the port number in the connection string.

Comment: Are there are error messages at the beginning of the ERRORLOG about any problems connecting to the SQL Brower?

Answer (score 0):

Does sound rather strange. I have used portqry to resolve issues in the past. Might be worth giving it a try

[This blog post explains how to use it](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/troubleshooting-port-related-connectivity-issues-with-portqry/)